# Magento 2.3.5, custom option not show on configurable product

Tags: magento2.3

I have created configurable products with two attributes, some of the simple products associated with the configurable has a custom option.
In the product frontend, when I select the configuration, the option does not appear.

Instead, if I set the customized option on the main product, it appears.
But I need to show the option set on the associated product because the price varies according to the configurable product.

I would like to know if it is normal that the options are not shown for the simple products associated with the configurable?
Or, the custom options must be visible and therefore there is a bug?

Can you help me solve it?

Comment: Check attribute settings, 'used in product listing: yes', 'visible in catalog: yes'

Comment: Hi Ricky, the problem isn't attribute setting, but "Custom Option" set in configurable product. Have other suggest for me?

Comment: @Joso, Did you get any solution regarding this because I have also faced the same problem.